# как вернуть закладки в chrome

Tags: google-chrome

После обновления браузера chrome - он поменялся. Теперь нужно использовать пользователей для использования самого браузера. В итоге закладки, история, и всё остальное, касающееся старого пользователя - исчезло.

**Как вернуть закладки?**